# Apresentar todos os icons do font awesome no meu website?

Tags: font-awesome

Eu gostaria de puder usar todos os ícone da `font-awesome 4.7` no meu `website` sem ter de escrever o código de cada ícone.

Não estou a falar de `iframe` porque quererei usar `Jquery events` neles.

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida, exatamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi você quer criar algo para exibir todos disponíveis sem precisar ter que ficar acessando a documentação, seria isto mesmo?

Você pode usar o `document.styleSheets` e depois o `cssRules` para capturar todas rules adicionadas no documento e filtrar para exibir somente as do font-awesome

Note que a filtragem tem que manter todas rules com como prefixo `fa-` e com sufixo `:before`, assim por exemplo:

```js
var removeUnused = /^\.|\:{1,}before/g;
var isFont = /\.fa-.*?:before/;

var sheet, rules, fontawesome = [];

for (var i = 0, style = document.styleSheets, j = style.length; i < j; i++) {
    sheet = style[i];
    
    if (!sheet) continue;
    
    rules = sheet.cssRules;
    
    if (!rules) continue;
    
    for (var x = 0, y = rules.length; x < y; x++) {
         if (!isFont.test(rules[x].selectorText)) continue;
         
         fontawesome.push(rules[x].selectorText.replace(removeUnused, ""));
    }
}

console.log(fontawesome);
```

```html
<style>
.fa-stack-2x{font-size:2em}.fa-inverse{color:#fff}.fa-glass:before{content:"\f000"}.fa-music:before{content:"\f001"}.fa-search:before{content:"\f002"}.fa-envelope-o:before{content:"\f003"}.fa-heart:before{content:"\f004"}.fa-star:before{content:"\f005"}.fa-star-o:before{content:"\f006"}.fa-user:before{content:"\f007"}.fa-film:before{content:"\f008"}.fa-th-large:before{content:"\f009"}
</style>
```

> Não adicionei o CDN porque o CORS impede o acesso ao `cssRules` de diferentes dominios, então este script só vai funcionar se você baixar o font-awesome e colocar no seu site.

Desta forma terá todas classe, então com elas você pode criar os elementos como desejar, assim por exemplo:

```
<script>
var removeUnused = /^\.|\:{1,}before/g;
var isFont = /\.fa-.*?:before/;

var sheet, rules, fontawesome = [];

for (var i = 0, style = document.styleSheets, j = style.length; i < j; i++) {
    sheet = style[i];

    if (!sheet) continue;

    rules = sheet.cssRules;

    if (!rules) continue;

    for (var x = 0, y = rules.length; x < y; x++) {
         if (!isFont.test(rules[x].selectorText)) continue;

         fontawesome.push(rules[x].selectorText.replace(removeUnused, ""));
    }
}

var icones = document.querySelector("#icones"),
    resultado = [];

for (var i = 0, j = fontawesome.length; i < j; i++) {
     resultado.push('<i class="' + fontawesome[i] + '"></i>');
}

icones.innerHTML = resultado.join(", "); //Virgula é para separar os icones
</script>
```

Comment: Irei testar e darei feedback em breve

Comment: @I_like_trains fiz uma correção agora no código, precisava remover o before e o `.` das classes, não dá pra testar infelizmente no sandbox do Stack Overflow porque o CORS por segurança bloqueia. Me avisa qualquer coisa ;)

Comment: É exatamente disto que precisava, agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: @I_like_trains daqui a pouco vai aparecer 1 ou 2 novas respostas de pessoas que copiam parte da minha resposta e adicionam algo a mais só pra dizer que são melhores, mesmo que a base seja só possivel graças a minha resposta :/

Comment: A sua resposta foi aceite por isso já estou decidido a dar valor ao `Original Poster`

Comment: @I_like_trains obrigado, só estava comentando algo normal que ocorre quando respondo em CSS e HTML, infelizmente. Mas valeu e desculpe o desabafo :)

Comment: Eu nunca fui alvo disso felizmente mas eu compreendo a sua dor.